# NME android path location?

Tags: android, path, haxe, nme, haxelib

nme test `build.nmml` android

`Error: Could not find /Library/Android//extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar`

This is my error.

I see that there is a "//", but there should be a directory there normally my path is

`/Library/Android/android_sdk/...`

Can someone tell me where I can change this path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after hours of searching, i've found the file:

```
~/.hxcpp_config.xml
```

You can easily modify those line (with a sudo or a chmod, because it's in read only mode).

```
<xml>

    <section id="vars">

            <set name="ANDROID_SETUP" value="true" />
            <set name="ANDROID_NDK_ROOT" value="/Library/Android/android_ndk" />
            <set name="MAC_USE_CURRENT_SDK" value="1" />
            <set name="ANDROID_SDK" value="/Library/Android/android_sdk" />
            <set name="ANT_HOME" value="/Library/Android/apache_ant" />

    </section>

</xml>
```